# Output Values from gc into Hash Table

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Trying to make a hash table with 2 categories: Users and Passwords.
This is my code thus far but the issue is the output only displays the command and does not execute it.

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){
$caps = [char[]] "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXY"
$lows = [char[]] "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxy" 
$nums = [char[]] "2346789"
$spl = [char[]] "!@#$%^&*?+"

$first = $lows | Get-Random -count 1;
$second = $caps | Get-Random -count 1;
$third = $nums | Get-Random -count 1;
$forth = $lows | Get-Random -count 1;
$fifth = $spl | Get-Random -count 1;
$sixth = $caps | Get-Random -count 1;

$pwd = [string](@($first) + @($second) + @($third) + @($forth) + @($fifth) + @($sixth))

Out-File C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\L8_userpasswords.txt -InputObject $pwd -Append

}

$here = @'
$users=Get-Content C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\L8_users.txt
$passwords=Get-Content C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\L8_userpasswords.txt
'@
convertfrom-stringdata -stringdata $here
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\l8.ps1

Name            Value
----            -----
$users          Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Lab8_users.txt
$passwords      Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\L8_userpasswords.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this, which will turn the list of users and passwords into a `HashTable`, and then cast it to a `PSCustomObject`, which will have two properties: `Users` and `Passwords`.

```
$Data = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Users = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\L8_users.txt;
    Passwords = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\L8_userpasswords.txt;
}
$Data;
```

Comment: I am trying this but now my output just states:
`Name                           Value                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                         
Value                          {dV7a@H, wT9x+U, bU3y@Y, vC9s&R...}                                                           
Name                           {Mike Baker, Mary Martin, Uma Siveram, Uri Demisky...}`

Comment: @TazB. Please update your question with that information. It's not all that readable like this.

Answer (score 0):

Or hey, you could probably just replace the entire script with a one liner:

```
GC C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\L8_users.txt|%{[PSCustomObject]@{User=$_;Password=[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,3)}}
```

Unless you are super attached to your password generation loop that is. `[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(X,Y)` will generate complex passwords where X is the length and Y is the number of special characters (the rest will be a random mix of upper case letters, lower case letters, and numbers). So in my code (10,3) is a 10 character password with 3 non-alphanumeric characters.

You want it saved to a file? Pipe that to `Export-CSV`. Or assign it to a variable by prefixing it with something like `$UserList = <code>`.

Or if you really, really want a Hash Table you could make an empty one and then alter it just a little to add each pair to the table like this:

```
$UserList = @{}
GC C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\L8_users.txt|%{$UserList.add($_,[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,3))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `L8_users.txt` and `L8_userpasswords.txt` contain the same number of items, you could do something like this:

```
$users     = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\L8_users.txt'
$passwords = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\L8_userpasswords.txt'

$userpasswords = @{}
for ($i = 0; i -lt $users.Length; $i++) {
  $userpasswords[$users[$i]] = $passwords[$i]
}
```